# Grouping log message using RegEx with multiple semicolons

Tags: javascript, regex, grouping, log4net

I have problem with my RegEx to match log messages. We're using log4net and I want to group by *timestamp*, *level*, *logger* and *message*. The problem is that we're using semicolon to separate there groups and sometimes the message contains semicolon as well.

Example entries in the log file:

1. `2023-02-24 10:06:41,903;WARN;Request.Apply.Locked;business.Validator;Waiting X to continue` (working)
2. `2023-02-24 10:06:41,903;WARN;Request.Apply.Locked;business.Validator;Framework;&lt;METADATA&gtWaiting X to continue&lt;/METADATA&gt` (not working)

Link to RegEx:

1. https://regex101.com/r/E97VkI/1 (working)
2. https://regex101.com/r/n6Um82/1 (not working)

As you can see, the second link groups "/METADATA&gt" as the message.

The problem is that I don't know how many semicolon there are in the *message*. However, I know that it can be 1-3 semicolons in the *logger*. Is it possible to write a RegEx to match/ignore up to 3 semicolons?

As you can see in the below example, the *logger* will start and end with semicolon like this:
`;Request.Apply.Locked;business.Validator;Framework;Test;`

There we have 5 semicolons, but 3 of them should be part of the *logger* group.

The log can be as long as: 
`2023-02-24 10:06:41,903;WARN;Request.Apply.Locked;business.Validator;Framework;Test;&lt;METADATA&gtWaiting X to continue&lt;/METADATA&gt`

Here is my current RegEx:
`(?<timestamp>[\d-]+ [\d:,]+);(?<level>[A-Z]+)\s?;?\s?\s?(?<logger>[\s\S]*);(?<message>[\s\S]*)`

**To summarize:** I want a RegEx to group *timestamp*, *level*, *logger*, *message* and it should work for both example 1 and example 2.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could match a leading `;`, then 0-2 occurrences in between and an ending `;` using a quantifier and a negated character class:

```
(?<timestamp>[\d-]+ [\d:,]+);(?<level>[A-Z]+)\s*;\s*(?<logger>(?:[^;\n]*;){0,2}[^;\n]*);(?<message>.*)
```

**Explanation**

- `(?<timestamp>[\d-]+ [\d:,]+);` Group *timestamp*
- `(?<level>[A-Z]+)` Group *level* matching 1+ chars A-Z
- `\s*;\s*` Match `;` between optional whitespace chars (that you possible also match a newline)
- `(?<logger>` Group *logger*

  - `(?:[^;\n]*;){0,2}` Repeat 0-2 times any char except `;` and then match `;`
  - `[^;\n]*` Match optional chars other than `;` or a newline
- `);` Close group *logger* and match `;`
- `(?<message>.*)` Group *message* matching the rest of the line

See a  [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/cZxkqz/1).

---

Or if the `&lt;` should not be part of the logger:

```
(?<timestamp>[\d-]+ [\d:,]+);(?<level>[A-Z]+)\s*;\s*(?<logger>(?:(?!&[lg]t;).)*);(?<message>.*)
```

See another [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/u8hDmM/1)

Comment: Wow, that was a nice fix. Thanks a lot for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `m` regex modifier to match `^` and `$` at start and end of line respectively. Then make the last capture look for anything *except* a semi-colon.

```
 ^(?<timestamp>[\d-]+ [\d:,]+);(?<level>[A-Z]+)\s?;?\s?\s?(?<logger>[\s\S]*);(?<message>[^;]+)$
```

It works for examples 1. and 2. above.